# How to change the Drawing Rectangle and Thumb Image for a UISlider

Tags: swift, uislider

I'm new to swift and IOS programming in general and am looking for a simple way to change a `UISlider's` thumb Image and thumb size. I found the class reference page for the `UISlider`, but don't fully understand how to implement the `currentThumbImage` property and `thumbRectForBounds` override. As an end goal, 
I need a thumb circle thingy thats bigger than the default circle slider thumb thingy. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setThumbImage`

e.g.:

```
var img = UIImage(/*...*/)
@IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!

slider.setThumbImage(img, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

`currentImage` and `thumbImageForState` are *read-only* (query-only) properties. Similarly, `thumbRectForBounds` is informational, not intended to be overridden.

Comment: How to set size of the image ? @BaseZen